# markov chain - probability question

Tags: probability, self-study, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Transition matrix has been written like that;

$$\mathcal P = \begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & 0  & 2/3 \\  1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3  \\  0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$$

the initial vector is that

$$\pi_0 = \begin{bmatrix}  1/5 & 4/5 &0\end{bmatrix}$$

what is the probability of null at step 5=?

---

0 and 1 is transition statement when we look at the P matrix. 2 is the null statement when we look at the P matrix.

the asked probability is equal to $ P_0 f_{02}^5 + P_1 f_{12}^5$

where $f_{02}^5 $ means that by starting in 0, the probability of being in 2 at first time and with 5 steps. this equal to $(1/3)^4×(2/3)$

but i cannot calculate $f_{12}^5$.

please help me calculating this. thank you

Comment: _Hint:_ $f_{02}^5$ is the $(0,2)$ element of the matrix $\mathcal{P}^5$.

Comment: "where $f_{02}^5 $ means that by starting in 0, the probability of being in 2 at first time and with 5 steps" Actually, $f_{02}^5 $ is the probability of being in 2 after 5 steps, starting from 0, whether this is the first visit of 2 or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$\mathcal P = \begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & 0  & 2/3 \\  1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3  \\  0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$$then$$\mathcal P^5 = \begin{bmatrix} 1/3^5 & 0  & 1-1/3^5 \\  5/3^5 & 1/3^5 & 1-6/3^5  \\  0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$$by drawing the transition diagram.